# React suite inputpicker and pagination component. accessibility

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, wai-aria, rsuite

Inputpicker and pagination contain multiple input field.While putting aria-label tag, those component are not being accessible.
[image]

```
 <InputPicker
    role="combobox"
    id={id}
    {...rest}
    data={options as ISelectOption[]}
    id={id}     
  
  />
<label htmlFor={id} className="floating-label">
    {placeholder}
  </label>
```

Is there a workaround for this issue?

Comment: The screenshot seems to be of the icons in the WAVE accessibility checker. The error associated with those icons is that there isn't a label for that element?  It's not quite clear from your question.  Can you also post the HTML that gets generated?